# autossh not working when executed in python

Tags: python, linux, terminal, subprocess, autossh

I am trying to create ssh reverse tunnel. When I run the below command on terminal it works greate:

```
autossh -M 10876 -N -f -o PubkeyAuthentication=yes -o PasswordAuthentication=no -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa -R 6666:localhost:22 root@**.**.**.** -p 2233
```

But when I run it in python with `os.system()` or using `subprocess` it's not working. When I check the processes list the process is created and running and has no difference with the last method.(running directly in terminal)

python code:

```
command ='autossh -M 10876 -N -f -o PubkeyAuthentication=yes -o PasswordAuthentication=no -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa -R 6666:localhost:22 root@**.**.**.** -p 2233'
proc = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(command), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

Any idea What's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you are using `shell=True`, you don't want to use `shlex.split()` on the command arguments... it should just be a string.

Since you are passing args to `Popen` as a sequence, the first arg (`autossh`) is used as the command, and the rest of the args are actually passed to the *shell*, not to `autossh`.

So... you can either remove `shell=True`, or pass args as a string by removing use of `shlex.split()`.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen

Comment: I tried your answer but it made no difference. still I can't establish the ssh connection.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me in Windows10 (autossh in cygwin, Python 3.6)
`port = 6379;
command = f'autossh -M 1{port} -N -f -C -L {port}:localhost:{port} root@acone2';
proc = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(command), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)`